# UnitTest autorunner on Intellij IDEA for java

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, tdd, autorun

I try to use plugin 'fireworks' http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=1106 for autrorunning unittests for java code. but it doesn't work. Is any alternative for it?

Is anybody autroexecute unittests for java code after sources have changed?

## PS

My project is tiny - it's just exercise for Algorithms courses so i don't want build complex deployment system on Maven or something to resolve so trivial tasks. So if any plugin for IDEA has exist it will be better for me.

But if you have simple decision on Maven it also can fit to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the ^S to run the tests (^shiftR) that would pretty much give you what you are after(I think).

Then Set the test runner to always save before running.

Then every time you do a ^S the tests will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Infinitest also suits this purpose. For larger projects it becomes annoying but for your small project it should work well. Also, it works well in Eclipse.